# Custom terminal command - C#

Tags: c#, terminal, macos-sierra

I wrote a C # code for a count of PDF pages in a specific directory.
How can I create a new terminal command in MacOS that invokes the C# code?

Comment: what's the question here? You want to run binary file? you want to compile and run C# code? you want to add a environment variable for terminal?

Comment: @Prajwal I have the exe file on my mac running with VisualStudio. I would have a terminal command that invoke this exe file

Comment: You cannot execute exe file on mac. Unless you are planning to use wine refer this section 3.1.1 https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide

Comment: Just out of curiosity @NanaGame are you using Visual Studio for Mac preview?

Comment: Yes, I use Visual Studio on mac, why? @Prajwal